# Why in the below case @value("${someProperty}") is working while @value("#{someProperty}"), is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have the below spring configuration:

```xml
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:commonSql.properties" />
```

Now in my class, when I use `@value("#{someproperty}")` it did not work. Then, I changed to
`@value("${someproperty}")` and it worked.

According to answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322632/spring-expression-language-spel-with-value-dollar-vs-hash-vs) questions `@value("#{someproperty}")`  is SpEL syntax, which is far more capable and complex. It can also handle property placeholders, and a lot more besides but in my case why it's not working  ? While the simple one is working how both $ and # are use to evaluate the value.

The main thing is `@value("#{someproperty}")` is not working while `@value("${someproperty}")` is working.

Comment: See here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322632/spring-expression-language-spel-with-value-dollar-vs-hash-vs

Comment: @Bob Flannigon according the answers of the questions both are same so both should work but here it's not working when i put #

Comment: Stackoverflow's very own [`el`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) tag has some great information on this

Answer (score 5):

`#{ }` is an expression language feature, while `${ }` is a simple property placeholder syntax.

*Expression language* means that there is a specific syntax, objects, variables and so on.

When you write "#{someproperty}", you actually referring to the object and *expression language engine* answers you:

> Field or property 'someproperty' cannot be found on object of type
>   'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'

Here is what will work:

```
  @Value("#{'${someproperty}'}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source code of spring which shows the expression of getting a property key, and the reason is quite obvious, maybe help you:)

```
/** 
 * Abstract base class for PropertyEditors that need 
 * to resolve placeholders in paths. 
 * 
 * <p>A path may contain ${...} placeholders, to be resolved as 
 * system properties: e.g. ${user.dir}. 
 * 
 * @author Juergen Hoeller 
 * @since 1.1.2 
 * @see #PLACEHOLDER_PREFIX 
 * @see #PLACEHOLDER_SUFFIX 
 * @see System#getProperty(String) 
 */  
public class AbstractPathResolvingPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {  

    public static final String PLACEHOLDER_PREFIX = "${";  

    public static final String PLACEHOLDER_SUFFIX = "}";  

    protected static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(  
            AbstractPathResolvingPropertyEditor.class);  
  ...etc
```