# how to set properties file under classpath in spring using sts

Tags: spring-mvc, properties, spring-data

i am learning spring and trying to understand retrieve value from properties file.

I am trying the following way to try out some samples

```
<util:properties id="spelProp" location="classpath:/META-INF/spelProperties.properties"></util:properties>
```

where the content of spelProperties.properties are

```
spelTeacher.firstName="First name from Properties"
spelTeacher.lastName="Last name from properties"
```

I try to access the lastName inorder to set one of the bean property like

```
<bean id="spelTeacher3Xml" class="com.learningweb.Service.SpelSampleTeacher">
<property name="lastName" value="#{spelProp[spelTeacher.lastName]}" />
</bean>
```

When i try to run using STS
    i am getting an error that 
    "/META-INF/spelProperties.properties" does not exists.

Can someone help me to understand what is wrong here.
Did i miss any item in configuring classpath or any Spring framework related settings?

Appreciate your help
(Also any refernce to understand "classpath:" would be helpful. I tried to search but i am getting the right material i am looking for. I am trying to understand what does classpath: does in spring)
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try something like this instead:

```
    <bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">  
        <property name="locations">  
            <list>  
                <value>classpath:/META-INF/spelProperties.properties</value>  
            </list>  
        </property>  
    </bean>
```

or

```
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties" />
```

And then access it in spelTeacher3Xml like: `value="${spelTeacher.lastName}"`

Depending on your version of Spring, checkout the API for [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.7.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) or some other more specialized version of that.

[This guys site](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/) has a lot of basic Spring configuration tutorials. They may be a little dated, though.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.
I have a question about using ${} i read the SPel is actually #{}. are both one and the same?

Comment: For the most part, they are both acceptable for the given purposes, SpringEL is just capable of more. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322632/spring-expression-language-spel-with-value-dollar-vs-hash-vs)