# Spring 4 @Value where property default is a java system property

Tags: java, spring

In Spring 4, using the @Value annotation, what is the right way to specify a system property as a default if a specified property does not exists?

Whereas this works for the no-default case:

```
@Value("${myapp.temp}")
private String tempDirectory;
```

This doesn't work when I need a default:

```
@Value("#{myapp.temp ?: systemProperties.java.io.tmpdir}")
private String tempDirectory;
```

Nor does this:

```
@Value("#{myapp.temp ?: systemProperties(java.io.tmpdir)}")
private String tempDirectory;
```

Both of these give me an exception at the time Spring is trying to create the bean:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean  
     with name 'configurationService': Invocation of init method failed;
     nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Can this be done?

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: @chrylis -- Spring throws an exception when trying to create the bean. I've edited the question to be more explicit.

Comment: You have a "nested exception", which presumably has useful information. Post the *whole* stack trace.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I tried the following and it worked for me:

```
@Value("${myapp.temp:#{systemProperties['java.io.tmpdir']}}")
private String tempDirectory;
```

The missing parts for you I believe was not using `?:` and needing the `#{}`. According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5322737/91866):

> `${...}` is the property placeholder syntax. It can only be used to dereference properties.
>
> `#{...}` is SpEL syntax, which is far more capable and complex. It can also handle property placeholders, and a lot more besides.

So basically what is happening is we are telling Spring to first interpret `myapp.temp` as property placeholder syntax by using the `${}` syntax. We then use `:` instead of `?:` (which is called the [Elvis operator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-operator-elvis)) since the elvis operator only applies to Spring Expression Language expressions, not property placeholder syntax. The third part of our statement is `#{systemProperties['java.io.tmpdir']}` which is telling Spring to interpret the next expression as a Spring Expression and allows us to get system properties.

Comment: You don't need SpEL for that. `@Value("${myapp.temp:${java.io.tmpdir}}") works evenly wel..

Answer (score 1):

Try `systemProperties['java.io.tmpdir']`.

It's a map, so if the key has a dot in the name, you should use `[..]`

Answer (score 0):

For me it only works with different property-names (being property.name.a a key with a value in my application.properties and property.name.b a Environment-Variable) like:

```
@Value("${property.name.a:${property.name.b}}")
```

The same names didn´t work for me like expected (loading the default, when the first property isn´t present), e.g.:

```
@Value("${property.name.a:${property.name.a}}")
```