# What does $("something") mean in Java?

Tags: java

I was looking into some tutorial and stumbled on this code:

```
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    eventBus.on($("quotes"), receiver);
    publisher.publishQuotes(NUMBER_OF_QUOTES);
}
```

This is the first time I see `$("quotes")` in Java. I'd appreciate someone explaining to me what's going on there.

Here's the source:

https://github.com/spring-guides/deprecate-gs-messaging-reactor/blob/master/complete/src/main/java/hello/Application.java#L53

Update:

This is not a question about $ as Java variable name. I know that it's a valid variable name. However, the format of $("something") looks JQuery-like; hence threw me off thinking that it's a special directive or something.

Comment: `import static reactor.bus.selector.Selectors.$;`

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484210/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-a-variable-name

Comment: $ is just a static method of the Selectors class. Read its javadoc to know what it does.

Comment: It means to call the static method [`reactor.bus.selector.Selectors.$(T obj)`](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-bus/blob/master/src/main/java/reactor/bus/selector/Selectors.java#L68) with the given argument.

Comment: whoops - wrong one, duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322632/spring-expression-language-spel-with-value-dollar-vs-hash-vs

Comment: @mwallner It has nothing to do with Spring Expression Language (SpEL).

Comment: @mwallner not duplicate, the link you gave is about the String `"$(...)"` not the static call `$(...)`

Comment: It is stated in the JLS not to use `$` that way. "The $ sign should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems."

Comment: You mean your answer, and I added emphasis to that point there as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of $ in a variable name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484210/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-a-variable-name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is just a call to the method called `$` that is statically imported:

```
import static reactor.bus.selector.Selectors.$;
```

it is just a normal method with a *strange* name.

'$' is a valid character for identifiers according the [Java Language Specification 3.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)

> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin  letters A-Z (\u0041-\u005a), and a-z (\u0061-\u007a), and, for  historical reasons, the ASCII underscore (_, or \u005f) and  dollar sign ($, or \u0024). The $ sign should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access  pre-existing names on legacy systems.

Comment: @maresa similar to having a line with `http://www.example.com/index` as a normal source code line in the middle of method- it is just a label (`http:`) followed by a comment (`// ...`)

Comment: The quote cited shows that that is not a good name for a function.

Comment: @LewBloch I am not responsible for that method/package/library neither is the questions author (I think)

Comment: I knew $ is legal char for names but I guess it threw me off cas it makes the code looks like JQuery-like.

Answer (score 4):

You have an `import static reactor.bus.selector.Selectors.$;`

From the [documentation](https://jar-download.com/java-documentation-javadoc.php?a=reactor-bus&g=io.projectreactor&v=2.0.8.RELEASE) that is *a short-hand alias for [`object(T)`](https://jar-download.com//javaDoc/io.projectreactor/reactor-bus/2.0.8.RELEASE/reactor/bus/selector/Selectors.html#object-T-)* which in turn *creates a [`Selector`](https://jar-download.com//javaDoc/io.projectreactor/reactor-bus/2.0.8.RELEASE/reactor/bus/selector/Selector.html) based on the given object.*