# Unable to use @Value annotation in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have a class

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class EmailSender {

    private Properties properties;
    @Value("#{mail.smtp.starttls.enable}") private String startTls;
    @Value("#{mail.transport.protocol}") private String protocol;
    @Value("#{mail.smtp.auth}") private String auth;
    @Value("#{mail.smtp.host}") private String host;
    @Value("#{mail.user}") private String user;
    @Value("#{mail.password}") private String password;
   ...
}
```

And the following properties in `application.properties`

```
# Email Credentials
mail.user                   = someone@somewhere.com
mail.password               = mypassword

# Sending Email
mail.smtp.host              = smtp.gmail.com
mail.from                   = someone@somewhere.com
mail.smtp.starttls.enable   = true
mail.transport.protocol     = smtp
mail.smtp.auth          = true
mail.subject            = my subject...
```

But when I start the application, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'emailSender': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'startTls'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'mail' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
```

How can I read these properties using @Value?

To be honest I've tried many times to use @Value but can never see to quite get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use property reference with `$` instead of SpEL expression with `#`

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class EmailSender {

    private Properties properties;
    @Value("${mail.smtp.starttls.enable}") private String startTls;
    @Value("${mail.transport.protocol}") private String protocol;
    @Value("${mail.smtp.auth}") private String auth;
    @Value("${mail.smtp.host}") private String host;
    @Value("${mail.user}") private String user;
    @Value("${mail.password}") private String password;
   ...
}
```

You can read more about `$`  vs. `#` in the question [Spring Expression Language (SpEL) with @Value: dollar vs. hash ($ vs. #)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322632/spring-expression-language-spel-with-value-dollar-vs-hash-vs/5322737#5322737)