# Spring Expression Language dollar vs hash ($ vs #)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm a little confused concerning when to use `$` compared to `#`.
Spring documentation only uses `#`.

I need to know when to use `$` and when `#`?
Can I use `#` in the MVC JSP pages?

Comment: Duplicate: [Spring Expression Language (SpEL) with @Value: dollar vs. hash ($ vs. #)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322632/spring-expression-language-spel-with-value-dollar-vs-hash-vs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5322737/814702):

> `${...}` is the *property placeholder* syntax. It can only be used to dereference properties.
>
> `#{...}` is [*SpEL*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/expressions.html) syntax, which is far more capable and complex. It can also handle property placeholders, and a lot more besides.
>
> Both are valid, and neither is deprecated.

Comment: _"There is no JSP EL, JSP uses SpEL"_ You may want to remove this incorrect statement before you receive any downvotes.