# Injecting property in Springboot using @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

I am using Spring and Java for an application, and I want to use the `@Value` annotation to inject the value of the property, my use case is that I want first to check if that property exists as system property (so it takes priority), and otherwise default to a configuration property (existing in the properties file)

In the commented code you can see what I am trying to achieve, is that possible to default to something else that a simple string? If it is not, how can I achieve this?

```
//@Value("#{configProperties['local.datasource.username']}") THIS IS THE ORIGINAL CODE
//@Value("#{systemProperties['some.key'] ?: 'my default system property value'}") THIS IS HOW SPRING PROPOSE TO SET A DEFAULT VALUE
//@Value("#{systemProperties['some.key'] ?: #{configProperties['local.datasource.username']}}") THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE, HOWEVER NOT COMPILING,
private String username;
```

Comment: Instead of using the elvis operator, SpEL supports defaults with `:` IIRC on your third example the first `#` should be a `$` and imho the expressions don't have to be of collective types: `${some.key:local.datasource.username}`

Comment: That worked! thanks, should you add the comment as answer in order to set this as resolved?

Comment: Glad to hear, I wrote an answer and added some additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for are simple *Property Palceholders*.

While the [Spring Expression Language](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html) supports the `#{}` syntax for rather complex expressions (ternary, calls, expressions, math), injecting property values and defaults is in most cases better done using a simple property placeholder `${value:defaultValue}` approach:

```
@Property("${some.key:local.datasource.username}")
private String username;
```

Where `some.key` is being resolved (independent of its origin), and if that is null, Spring defaults to the value of `local.datasource.username`.

Please keep in mind, that even if `some.key` is present, Spring will throw an exception when it can't resolve your default property.

See also:

- [Spring Expression Language (SpEL) with @Value: dollar vs. hash ($ vs. #)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322632/spring-expression-language-spel-with-value-dollar-vs-hash-vs) and
- [A Quick Guide to Spring @Value](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation)

Comment: For clarity, `${...}` is NOT SpEL. They are property placeholders that existed for many years before SpEL was introduced.

Comment: Yes, that's correct and described in the question I referred. I edited the answer to make it more clear.